# Sorting lines alphabetically in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev, alphabetical

I have a Python class:

```
class PatientParamStruct:
    output_folder = ''
    condition_timestamps = None # list cannot be initialized here!
    lag_time = 0
    lead_time = 0
    feature_numbers = None
    input_feature_folder = ''
    input_folder_validation = ''
    patient_number = 0
    lag_number_of_windows = 0
    samples_per_second = 0
    prediction_window = 0
    moving_window_time = 0
    subwindow_lag_time = 0
```

[image]

Can I sort alphabetically a bunch of lines in Eclipse PyDev?

In this case the output would be:

```
class PatientParamStruct:
    condition_timestamps = None # list cannot be initialized here!
    feature_numbers = None
    input_feature_folder = ''
    input_folder_validation = ''
    lag_number_of_windows = 0
    lag_time = 0
    lead_time = 0
    moving_window_time = 0
    output_folder = ''
    patient_number = 0
    prediction_window = 0
    samples_per_second = 0
    subwindow_lag_time = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

Ctrl+Shift+O

It's the same binding used for the organize imports, but if some text is selected it'll sort the text (and if no text is selected it'll organize imports and try to add new imports for unresolved tokens).